# Implement buzz feature

Tags: c#

I would like to implement the buzz feature in our chat messenger. I created the balloon tooltip and flash for highlighting the presence of new message while the chat window is in minimized state. The code is given below.but now i wished to implement the buzz feature on mouse click or key press to restore the chat window in maximized state.

```
this.nfiBroadcast.Icon = Resource1.chat;
nfiBroadcast.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "New broadcast message received..!", "" 
     + msg.senderDisplayName 
     + " messaged you.", ToolTipIcon.Info);

if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
{                       
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    FlashWindow.Flash(this, 3);
}
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Please spend some time on formatting your question and code next time

Comment: Do you mean you want to restore the window from minimized state when the user presses a key or clicks the mouse?

Comment: I mean, assume if A and B are two persons.they chat with each other through the messenger.A minimized his chat window.Then B send a message to A.But A cannot identify it.So to get the attention of A, B Press 'ctrl+g'(like yahoo messenger).At that time,A's minimized window need to come in the normal state and shake to get the attention of A..

Comment: So what is your problems? Restoring the window, or shaking it? It seems that you have a `FlashWindow` class.

Comment: The flash is set to only '3' times.After that it didn't flash.If during that time interval,A didn't notice that flash,then how could he identify it later?That's why i think about the buzz feature.so that,the window will restore in normal form and shake.I think it will definitely get the attention of A.

Comment: Ring the bell to catch the attention of Mr. A :)

Comment: @Ali.NET:thanks for your comment.I'm successfully implement this feature using some simple code in addition with the chat window shaking feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resotre a window from minized state, just set the `WindowState` to `FormWindowState.Normal`:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```